How to create a dynamic sitemap in Angular?
I created a dynamic sitemap in my Angular project, but the last modified of all pages changes in each build. I just want the last modified of the page I made changes to change. How do I do this?
const baseUrl = "https://blabla.com/";
const untrackedUrlsList = [
  baseUrl + "dashboard"
];

const options = { compact: true, ignoreComment: true, spaces: 4 };

const updateSitemap = () => {
  const srcPath = path.join(__dirname, "sitemap.xml");
  const distDir1 = path.join(__dirname, "..", "dist", "cotcast", "browser");
  const distDir2 = path.join(__dirname, "..", "dist", "cotcast");
  const distPath1 = path.join(distDir1, "sitemap.xml");
  const distPath2 = path.join(distDir2, "sitemap.xml");


  fs.readFile(srcPath, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    let sitemapJSON = JSON.parse(convert.xml2json(data, options));

    sitemapJSON.urlset.url = [];

    untrackedUrlsList.forEach((ele) => {

      sitemapJSON.urlset.url.push({

        loc: { _text: ele },

        lastmod: { _text: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD") },

      });

    });

    const finalXML = convert.json2xml(sitemapJSON, {

      ...options,

      xmlDeclaration: true,

    });

    fs.mkdir(distDir1, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
   
   if (err) throw err;
     
 fs.writeFile(distPath1, finalXML, (err) => {

        if (err) throw err;

      });

    });


    fs.mkdir(distDir2, { recursive: true }, (err) => {

      if (err) throw err;
     

      fs.writeFile(distPath2, finalXML, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
    });

  });
};


updateSitemap();




For example, when I make a change on the about page and get a build, only the about date should appear in the sitemap.
